# Background color is not showing

Tags: html, css, forms, background-color

I was trying to build a form. I want to add a background color for that, but the color is being shown in the page.

I tried clear, block and everything. When I inspect, it's shows that the background color works, but it doesn't show the color on the page.

**Here is the HTML code :**

```html
<?php //include 'session.php'; ?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>User Edit Form</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>

<body class="UserEdit">
  <div class=" container">
    <div class="edit_form">
      <div class="form_start">
        <h1>This Form Page for UserEdit Page</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, I just wanted to add a background color for .edit_form div. But it's not working.

**Here is the CSS :**

```css
.edit_form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

.form_start {
  position: fixed;
  top: 4em;
  background: rgb(0 0 0 / 0%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgb(0 0 0 / 60%);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I added screenshots for better understanding. [Image of problem with inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7i3B.png)

Comment: The .form_start position:fixed causes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Setting an element to `position: fixed` takes it out of normal flow.

Elements outside of normal flow have no influence on the size of their containers.

The **only** element inside `.edit_form` has `position: fixed`.

This means that there are no elements inside `.edit_form` that influence its height.

This makes its height `0`.

Since it has no height, it has no area to display the background colour on (`any width * 0 = 0 pixels`).

---

There are a number of ways you could change this including:

- Give it an explicit height
- Put some content (in normal flow) inside it
- Set the background on the positioned element instead
- Position it instead of positioning its child

Answer (score 0):

**Is This What u Want**

```css
.edit_form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  
}
.form_start {
  margin: auto;
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgb(0 0 0 / 60%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Edit Form</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body class="UserEdit">
    <div class=" container" >
        <div class="edit_form" >
            <div class="form_start" >
                <h1>This Form Page for UserEdit Page</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```css
.edit_form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  
}
.form_start {
  margin: auto;
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgb(0 0 0 / 60%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Edit Form</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body class="UserEdit">
    <div class=" container" >
        <div class="edit_form" >
            <div class="form_start" >
                <h1>This Form Page for UserEdit Page</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
</body>
```